# How do i pass data from a django function to another function

Tags: python, django, database-relations

I have this signup django app and its more like a signup page for a website. I have an issue now, i made a one to one database relationship between the users data and their web profile

```
from django.db import models
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone


class UserDetail(models.Model):
    SEX = (
        ('M', 'Male'),
        ('F', 'Female'),
    )
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=SEX)
    email = models.EmailField()

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)


class WebDetail(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(UserDetail, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    # TODO: i need to search how to do auto_now_add function
    # time_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

and here is my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .forms import UserDetailForm, WebDetailForm
from .models import UserDetail, WebDetail
from django.shortcuts import redirect, reverse


def index(requests):
    form = UserDetailForm()
    if requests.method == "POST":
        form = UserDetailForm(requests.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            UserDetail.objects.create(**form.cleaned_data)
            # print(requests.POST['first_name'])
            # return HttpResponse('<h1>Hello</h1>')
            # return redirect('signup:web_detail_create')
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(requests, 'signup/index.html', context)


def web_detail_create(requests):
    form = WebDetailForm()
    if requests.method == "POST":
        form = UserDetailForm(requests.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # TODO: i need the function above to go with the users data and that would be refrenced as the user
            #   of the password and the username.
            WebDetail.objects.create(**form.cleaned_data)
            return redirect('signup:final')
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(requests, 'signup/final.html', context)
```

now i want to be able to pass in the users data to the web_detail_create view.

Thanks for your contribution

Comment: If I correctly understand your problem, you want to pass the user details. If that's the case then you can pass the UserDetails Model object itself to the web_detail_create view function.

Comment: Your views.py in Django define a REST API. So a client application would pass the user's data to `web_detail_create` by sending a POST "request" to your server using the url you assigned to your app's view in your urls.py file ... along with payload data that contains the user data.

Comment: I think I tried that except you could just show me how to pass the UserDetail model object to the view

Comment: I'm a bit new to django and I haven't really gone deep into it like using the REST Api